# BlueprintJS / React - trouble retrieving TagInput > Tag value via onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

In a React/BlueprintJS app, I have a **TagInput**.  I need to access the string value of any **Tag** when clicked. For simplicity, let's assume I just need to `console.log(value)`.

I can't seem to locate the Tag's value in the callback. Based on [the documentation](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tag-input), I believe I need to pass an onClick function within `tagProps`. However, nothing I've tried seems to return the string value.

I've created a basic example here, see errors in console after clicking on any Tag:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blueprint-sandbox-7jsb3?fontsize=14

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: did you go to [**the source code**](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/docs-app/src/examples/core-examples/tagInputExample.tsx) for that example? The change is on the input not the tags. It gives you a list of tags that are remaining minus the one you clicked `x` on

Comment: Hi JDR, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think warning itself is self explanatory.

React has a **pool of synthetic event**, means it assigns a event to a handler and after the handler invokes it release that event back to the pool.

```
const handleTagClick = x => console.log(x);
```

In the above code `x` is nothing but the `synthetic event` which gets nullifies and released to event pool after your `TagInput` gets displayed on the screen.

So when you try to click, you are getting warning. The simple way to get rid of this warning is printing `currentTarget`.

```
const handleTagClick = x => console.log(x.currentTarget.innerText);
```

The above code will print the exact target which is clicked.

Another way is using `event.persist()`,

```
const handleTagClick = x => {
  x.persist();
  console.log(x.currentTarget.innerText);
}
```

**But I think it will be very slow in your case, so don't use it.**

Read more about [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/taginput-example-6b6f1?fontsize=14)